# How to run a http get in Angular in one component after updating data in another using Subject and next

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe

I'm using Angular and Express for my server. I want my product.component to refresh once I edit or enter a new product in admin.component. I was able to get it working partially by using the shopping.service with Subject and adding next in the admin.component at line 125 and subscribe in the constructor in the product.compoent but I'm getting a strange behavior: sometimes on the first time I edit a product the page updates, but then on the second time I edit it doesn't and vice versa.

thanks

project on github https://github.com/YehonatanGitHub/eCommerce

product.component:

```
import { DataService } from 'src/app/shared/data.service';
import { Product } from './product.model';
import { ShoppingService } from '../../shopping.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css'],
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  public loadedProducts = [];
  private refreshSub: Subscription;
  private getDataSub: Subscription;

  constructor(private dataService: DataService, private shoppingService: ShoppingService) {
    this.refreshSub = this.shoppingService.refreshProducts.subscribe(() => {
      console.log("getallproducts");
      this.ngOnInit();
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllProducts();
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.refreshSub.unsubscribe();
    this.getDataSub.unsubscribe();
  }
  private getAllProducts() {
    this.getDataSub = this.dataService.fetchProducts()
      .subscribe((data) => this.loadedProducts = data);
  }

  clickEditProduct(editProduct: Product) {
    console.log(editProduct);
    this.shoppingService.statuseEditProduct.next(editProduct);
  }}
```

admin.component:

```
onSubmit(postData: Product) {
    if (this.editProduct == undefined) {
      console.log("NEW product sent to POST");
      this.newProduct = postData;
      this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/admin/add-product', postData)
          .subscribe(responseData => {
          console.log(responseData);
        });
      this.productForm.setValue({
        proname: "",
        price: "",
        picture: "",
        category: ""
      });
      this._opened = false;
    } else {

      let productEditInfo = {
        _id: this.editProduct._id,
        proname: postData.proname,
        price: postData.price,
        picture: postData.picture,
        category: postData.category
      }
      console.log(productEditInfo);
      this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/admin/edit-product', productEditInfo)

        .subscribe(responseData => {
          console.log(responseData);
        });
      console.log("Edit product sent");
      this.productForm.setValue({
        proname: "",
        price: "",
        picture: "",
        category: ""
      });
      this.editProduct = undefined;
      this._opened = false;

    }
    this.shoppingService.refreshProducts.next();
  }
}
```

ShoppingService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../shopping/products/product/product.model';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs'
@Injectable()
export class ShoppingService {

    statuseEditProduct = new Subject<Product>();
    refreshProducts = new Subject<void>();

    constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: Well, I could be wrong, but please check once again that your putting the refresh code inside the constructor, which will run only once

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `this.shoppingService.refreshProducts.next();` in the `onSubmit` method, without waiting for the product to actually be saved. So the product component sends the request to refresh itself immediately after the service has sent a request to save the product. The requests are thus handled concurrently by your server. So sometimes the refresh request will see the updated/created product, and sometimes it won't.

To fix the issue, only ask the product component to update once you have received the response to the create/update request.

Comment: Hi JB thanks so much, that makes perfect sense. Can you recommend what to add to achieve this? thx

Comment: Well, remove the call to `this.shoppingService.refreshProducts.next();`, and add it where it must be added, i.e. when you know you have received the response. These places are where you're currently *printing* the response to the console.

Comment: Thank you so much JB, this helped me realize that my response on the server was not set correctly.  I needed to change it to: res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Email sent successfully.'
    });         and now it's working. thanks again